# Converting Python enumerate into Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to convert a function of python code into JavaScript.

The `arr` variable is an array such as `[2, 5, 3, 1]`. Basically, I want to create a list of tuple where each tuple contains as first value the position of the element in the `arr` and as second value the element of the `arr`. Then, I want to do the same for the **reversed** of `arr`

**Python code:**

```
def myPositions(arr):
    positions = sorted(list(enumerate(arr)), key=lambda e: e[1])
    return positions

def final(arr):
    print("Reversed", arr[::-1]) # [ 1, 3, 5, 2 ]
    print(myPositions(arr)) # [(3, 1), (0, 2), (2, 3), (1, 5)]
    print(myPositions(arr[::-1])) # [(0, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5)]
```

**My JavaScript code**

Since there is no enumerate in JavaScript (this is what I think), I did the following:

```
function myPositions(arr) {
    let positions = arr.map((e,i) => [i, e]).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1] )
    return positions
}

function final(arr) {
    let reversedArr = arr.reverse()
    console.log("Reversed", reversedArr) // [ 1, 3, 5, 2 ]
    let x = myPositions(arr)
    console.log(x) // [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 5 ] ]
    let y = myPositions(reversedArr)
    console.log(y) // [ [ 0, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 5 ] ] This is different than  print(myPositions(arr[::-1]))

}
```

I do not get why it works the same if I do not reverse the array.
But with the reversed array, I get two different results.
In python I get `[(0, 1), (3, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5)]`, in JS I get `[ [ 0, 1 ], [ 3, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 2, 5 ] ]`

Comment: There IS essentially an `enumerate` in Javascript, it's `array.entries()`

Comment: `Array.from(['a','b','c'].entries())`

Comment: [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) works in place, so `arr` is reversed as well as `reversedArr`.